# Python substitute a word for a word and the next concatenated

Tags: python, regex

I want to be able to take in a string and if r'\snot\s' is located, essentially concatenate 'not' and the next word (replacing the white space in between with an underscore).

So if the string is

string="not that my name is Brian and I am not happy about nothing"

The result after a regular expression would be:

'not_that my name is Brian and I am not_happy about nothing'

(not in nothing is not touched).

I need to locate 'not' that is either seperated by white space or at the start of a sentence and then join it to '_' and the next word.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `re.sub()` with saving groups:

```
>>> re.sub(r"not\s\b(.*?)\b", r"not_\1", string)
'not_that my name is Brian and I am not_happy about nothing'
```

`not\s\b(.*?)\b` here would match `not` followed by a space, followed by a word (`\b` are the word boundaries). The `(.*?)` is a capturing group that help us capture the word after the `not` that we can then reference in the substitution (`\1`).

Comment: That is nice! Would you mind describing what the regex does to help me understand?

Comment: (.*?) I have not seen before. It seems like just finding any characters then followed by a boundary would work, i.e. re.sub(r"not\s\b(.*\s)\b", r"not_\1", string) but it only finds the first one in the string, Much to learn

Answer (score 2):

Why not just use the replace method on strings? It's a bit more readable than regex.

```
>>> msg = "not that my name is Brian and I am not happy about nothing"
>>> msg.replace('not ', 'not_')
'not_that my name is Brian and I am not_happy about nothing'
```

Answer (score 1):

How about just:

```
\bnot\s
```

**Example:**

```
>>> string
'not that my name is Brian and I am not happy about nothing'

>>> re.sub(r'\bnot\s', 'not_', string)
'not_that my name is Brian and I am not_happy about nothing'
```